# Iterar por vários arquivos XMLs com Python

Tags: python, xml

Olá, pessoal.

Imaginem a seguinte situação:

Tenho um diretório com vários arquivos XMLs NFe e preciso movê-los por emitente(CNPJ) e/ou data de emissão para um outro diretório.

Já consegui iterar pelos elementos de um arquivo, apenas, e copiá-lo de um diretório para outro, caso esteja na condição estipulada, mas não sei como fazer isso com todos os arquivos. Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço!

Um dos XMLs analisados tem esta estrutura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 - <nfeProc versao="4.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  - <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
   - <infNFe Id="NFe16190119250367000191550030000618321111024017" versao="4.00">
    - <emit>
      <CNPJ>19250367000191</CNPJ> 
      <xNome>M B PRODUTOS ALIMENTICIOS LTDA</xNome>
```

Segue o código que fiz para lê um arquivo, somente.

```
import shutil
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'/Users/Jp/Desktop/teste.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
NFe = root.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}NFe')
infNFe = NFe.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}infNFe')
emit = infNFe.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}emit')
cnpj = emit.find('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}CNPJ')

if cnpj.text == '19250367000191':
  shutil.copy(r'/Users/Jp/Desktop/teste.xml', r'/Users/Jp/Desktop/Hiper')
  print(cnpj.text)
else:
  print('Não tem o CNPJ solicitado')
```

Uso a versão 3.7 do Python!

Neste novo schema, preciso copiar arquivos que tenham o atributo "AR_CENTRAL_PG1_V1"!

Segue o schema:

```
 - <XMLDataFile>
   - <Groups fileName="092449274_000059131.12097869.NFe16141204842563000420551000000591311003460046.SERVIDOR250.NDDigitaleFormsConnectorService7.xml" pjlHeaderData="" pjlFooterData="">
     - <Formulary>
       - <XMLHead>
        - <Form name="AR_HIPER_PG1_V1">
           <PrinterName>HP LaserJet P1505</PrinterName> 
           <RawData /> 
           <InsertInCold>1</InsertInCold> 
           <IsDanfe>1</IsDanfe> 
           <DocumentUser>FormsUser</DocumentUser> 
           <DocumentTitle>No Name</DocumentTitle> 
           <pjlHeaderData /> 
           <pjlFooterData /> 
           <AutomaticFields /> 
          </Form>
         </XMLHead>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você pode implementar uma função capaz de extrair o `CNPJ` do emissor a partir do arquivo `.XML` contendo os dados de uma Nota Fiscal Eletrônica.

O exemplo abaixo faz uso do módulo [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), que possui suporte a [`XPath`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), simplificando bastante o trabalho de *parsing* do `XML`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def obter_cnpj_emissor( arquivoNFe ):
    nsNFe = { "ns" : "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" }
    root = ET.parse( arquivoNFe ).getroot()
    node = root.findall( "./ns:NFe/ns:infNFe/ns:emit/ns:CNPJ", nsNFe )
    if( len(node) != 1 ):
        return None
    return node[0].text
```

Em seguida, tirando proveito do módulo [`OS`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html), escrevemos uma função capaz de retornar uma lista com o nome de todos os arquivos com a extensão `.XML` contidos em um diretório de forma **não recursiva**:

```
import os

def obter_arquivos_xml( diretorio ):
    ret = []
    for arq in os.listdir( diretorio ):
        if arq.endswith(".xml"):
            ret.append( os.path.join( diretorio, arq ) )
    return ret
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
import os

def obter_arquivos_xml( diretorio ):
    return [ os.path.join( diretorio, arq ) for arq in os.listdir( diretorio ) if arq.endswith(".xml") ]
```

E para finalizar, escreve-se uma função capaz de verificar o `CNPJ` do emissor de cada nota fiscal, copiando para um diretório de destino somente os arquivos `.XML` que satisfazem a condição:

```
import shutil

def copiar_arquivos( origem, destino, cnpj ):
    for arquivo in obter_arquivos_xml( origem ):
        if( cnpj == obter_cnpj_emissor( arquivo ) ):
            shutil.copy( arquivo, destino )
```

Juntando tudo:

```
import shutil
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def obter_cnpj_emissor( arquivoNFe ):
    nsNFe = { "ns" : "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" }
    root = ET.parse( arquivoNFe ).getroot()
    node = root.findall( "./ns:NFe/ns:infNFe/ns:emit/ns:CNPJ", nsNFe )
    if( len(node) != 1 ):
        return None
    return node[0].text

def obter_arquivos_xml( diretorio ):
    return [ os.path.join( diretorio, arq ) for arq in os.listdir( diretorio ) if arq.endswith(".xml") ]

def copiar_arquivos( origem, destino, cnpj ):
    for arquivo in obter_arquivos_xml( origem ):
        if( cnpj == obter_cnpj_emissor( arquivo ) ):
            print( "CNPJ '{}' encontrado no arquivo '{}'...".format(cnpj,arquivo) )
            print( "Copiando arquivo '{}' para diretorio '{}'".format(arquivo,destino) )
            shutil.copy( arquivo, destino )
        else:
            print("CNPJ '{}' NAO ENCONTRADO no arquivo '{}'.".format(cnpj,arquivo))

copiar_arquivos( "/Users/Jp/Desktop/", "/Users/Jp/Desktop/Hiper", "19250367000191" )
```

**EDIT:**

Você pode usar uma expressão [`XPath`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) para determinar se um arquivo `.XML` possui uma determinada tag.

A função `check_form_name()` retorna a quantidade de vezes que que a tag `<FORM>` aparece no arquivo `.XML` com o atributo `name` contendo o valor que você especificar:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def check_form_name( arquivoNFe, nomeForm ):
    root = ET.parse( arquivoNFe ).getroot()
    node = root.findall( ".//Form[@name='{}']".format(nomeForm) )
    return len(node)
```

No caso abaixo, será printado na saída padrão a quantidade de vezes que a tag `<FORM>` aparece no arquivo `schema.xml` com o atributo `name` setado com o valor `AR_HIPER_PG1_V1`:

```
print(check_form_name("schema.xml","AR_HIPER_PG1_V1"))
```

Comment: Lacobus, boa tarde!

Comment: Vou testar seu código, obrigado pela força!

Comment: Olá, Lacobus.

Após testar o código, tá me retornando a seguinte mensagem:
> line 9, in obter_cnpj_emissor
    return node[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range

O que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: Esse erro indica que o CNPJ não foi encontrado no arquivo XML de entrada. Você poderia anexá-lo em sua pergunta ?

Comment: Anexei uma parte do XML!

Comment: @user139559: Eu fiz a inclusão de um controle de erros caso o CNPJ não possa ser extraído do arquivo XML adequadamente. Isso deve resolver o problema que você mencionou.

Comment: Boa tarde, Lacobus!

Seu código resolveu grande parte do problema, obrigado.

Porém, tenho um outro schema de xml que não consigo lê com esse código, você poderia me ajudar?

Vou anexar o novo schema na pergunta!

Comment: @user139559 Elabore uma nova pergunta com o schema que você citou. Separar as duas perguntas ficaria melhor.

Answer (score 0):

> Iterando na estrutura de um path em seu sistema de arquivos:

```
import os
path='/home/sidon/etc' 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        print(name)
```

No exemplo acima vc estara navegando em um generator, ou seja, ao termino da iteração o objeto estará "vazio", se vc quiser armazenar em uma variável na memória (O que pode ser altamente custoso), vc pode fazer, por exemplo:

```
tupla1 = tuple(os.walk('/home/sidon'))
```

> os.scandir

No python 3 vc tb pode fazer:

```
path='/home/sidon/etc'

for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file():
        print('Arquivo: ' + entry.path)
    elif entry.is_dir():
        print('Pasta: '+entry.path)
```

Output:

```
Arquivo: /home/sidon/etc/SHA256SUM.asc
Pasta: /home/sidon/etc/share
Pasta: /home/sidon/etc/mautic
Arquivo: /home/sidon/etc/QfrZL7R-debian-wallpaper.jpg
Arquivo: /home/sidon/etc/README.md
Arquivo: /home/sidon/etc/go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz

.......
```

> Editatada;
>   Para elucidar mais o uso do `walk` editei para adiconar mais um exemplo, para tentar deixar mais claro, aspós troca de comentários com o autor da pergunta:

Criei um diretorio de acordo com a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora veja o codigo e o output abaixo, então é só voce adaptar para o seu contexto

```
for dir_name, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    '''
    Note que o bloco abaixo poderia esta montando o path completo 
    de cada arquivo e realizando qq operação com eles.
    ''' 
    print('Diretorio: %s' % dir_name)
        for name in files:
        print('\t%s' % name)
```

Output do codigo acima:

```
Diretorio: /home/sidon/teste/
        teste1.txt
Diretorio: /home/sidon/teste/subteste
        texto4.txt
        texto2.txt
        texto3.txt
Diretorio: /home/sidon/teste/subteste2
        txt-sub2.txt
```

Comment: Sidon, muito obrigado pelo código.

Mas ainda tenho a dúvida de como iterar pelos arquivos, pois ainda tô iniciando com programação.

Comment: Com `os.walk` vc pode "navegar" nos arquivos de um diretorio de forma relativamente simples, estou editando a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Sidon, eu me expressei de forma errada. Preciso iterar pelas linhas dos  aquivos e movê-los de acordo com a condição estipulada.
Acredito que tenho que fazer um laço, mas nem como começar... Agradeço pela ajuda!!